# Does $z\mathscr Ex ∧x\mathscr E y ⇒ z\mathscr Ey$ imply $z\mathscr Ex ⇒ z\mathscr Ey$ if $z$ is arbitrary?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The proof of Theorem 3 regards $z\mathscr Ex$ $\land$ $x\mathscr E y$ $\Rightarrow$ $z\mathscr Ey$ implies $z\mathscr Ex \Rightarrow z\mathscr E y$. But I think it's not correct because the hypothesis $z\mathscr Ex$ $\land$ $x\mathscr E y$ and $z\mathscr Ex$ is different.

"Proof of Theorem 3

> (c) It follows immediately from (a) and (b) above that x/$\mathscr E$ = y/$\mathscr E \Rightarrow x \mathscr E$ y
>
> We need to prove that x$\mathscr E$ $y\Rightarrow x/\mathscr E = y/\mathscr E$
>
> Let x$\mathscr E$y. Then
>   $z\in x/\mathscr E \Rightarrow z\mathscr E x$   Def. 6

$\space\space\color{gray} {\text{The author repeats the conjunction of above two hypothesises in symbols as the following}}$

> $\underline {z\mathscr Ex \land x\mathscr E y \Rightarrow z\mathscr Ey}$ $\space\space\space\space\space\mathscr E$ is transitive.
>   $\underline {\Rightarrow z\in y/\mathscr E}$ $\space\space\space\space\space Def. 6$

$\color{gray}{\text {Now the author regards the above conclusion $z\mathscr E x \land x\mathscr E y \Rightarrow z\mathscr E y$ is equivaelnt to $z\mathscr E x \Rightarrow z\mathscr E y$ without revealing the justification to the reasoning}}$

$\color{green}{\text {Now I understand $z\mathscr E x \land x\mathscr E y \Rightarrow z\mathscr E y\equiv z\mathscr E x \Rightarrow (x\mathscr Ey\Rightarrow z\mathscr E y)$ by Exportation law in Example 7}}$

> Since $z$ is arbitrary, it follows that $x/\mathscr E \subseteq y/\mathscr E$. A similar argument gives $y/\mathscr E \subseteq x/\mathscr E$; hence $x/\mathscr E = y/\mathscr E$
>   "
>   Q.E.D.

FYI

> "**Theorem 3.** Let $\mathscr E$ be an equivalence relation on a nonempty set $X$. Then
>   (a) Each $x/\mathscr E$ is a nonempty subset of $X$.
>   (b)  $x/\mathscr E \cap y/\mathscr E \neq \emptyset$ if and only if $x\mathscr Ey$.
>   (c) $x\mathscr Ey$ if and only if $x/\mathscr E = y/\mathscr E$"
>   ...
>   **Definition 6**. Let $\mathscr E$ be an equivalence relation on a nonempty set $X$. For each $x\in X$, we define
>
> ​$X/\mathscr E=\{\,y∈X\mid y\mathscr E x\,\}$
>
> which is called the equivalence class determined by the element $x$.
>
> The set of all such equivalence classes on $X$ is denoted by $X/\mathscr E$; that is, $X/\mathscr E=\{\,x/\mathscr E\mid x∈X\,\}$.
>
> The symbol $X/\mathscr E$ is read "$X$ modulo $\mathscr E$," or simply "$X$ mod $\mathscr E$".
>
> **Example 7** Prove the following Exportation Law:
>   $\space\space\space\space\space p \land q \to r \equiv p \to (q\to r)$
>
> [Solution] $p\to (q \to r) \equiv p \to$ ~($q\land$ ~r)    Def. 4
>   $\space\space\space\space\equiv$ ~[$p\land(q\land$ ~r)]$\space\space Def. 4, D.N.$
>   $\space\space\space\space\equiv$ ~[($p\land q)\land$~r]$\space\space$ Assoc.
>   $\space\space\space\space\equiv p\land q\to r\space\space$ Def. 4
>
> Hence, p$\land q \to r \equiv p \to (q \to r)$
>
> **Definition 4**
>   The connective $\rightarrow$ is called the conditional and may be placed between any two statement p and q to form the compound statement p→q(reaad: "if p, then q". By definition the statement p→q is equivalent to the statement ~(p∧~q).

Source: Set Theory by You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T. Lin

Comment: You can review the def (and examples) of *valid argument*, page 24.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Oh I reviewed Laws of simplification in elementary logic chapter again "p∧q ⇒ p, p∧q ⇒ q" with the validity. But is there a justification that makes [(zEx ∧xEy ⇒ zEx) by Simp. ∧ (zEx ∧xEy ⇒ zEy) by trans.]⇒ (zEx⇒ zEy) valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the definition of *valid argument* [page 24-25]:

> A *formal proof of validity* for a given argument is a sequence of statements each of which is either a premise of the argument or follows from preceeding statments by a known valid argument, ending with the conclusion of the argument.

The proof begins with :

H1. $x\mathscr Ey$ --- premise of the argument

H2. $z\in x/\mathscr E$ --- 2nd premise of the argument

Def.6 : $z\in x/\mathscr E \Rightarrow z\mathscr E x$

Thus, by Modus Ponens [page 20], we have:

C. $z\mathscr E x$.

Up to now, we have proved:

> H1. $x\mathscr Ey$ and H2. $z\in x/\mathscr E$, therefore C. $z\mathscr E x$.

We can symbolize it as : $P,Q \Rightarrow R$.

Clearly: $P \Rightarrow P$ [see page 12 : $P \to P$ is a *tautology*] and thus, by properties of *implies*: $P,Q \Rightarrow P$.

By *Conjunction* [page 25]: $R,P \Rightarrow R \land P$.

Thus, putting all together, we have : $P, Q \Rightarrow R \land P$, i.e.:

> $x\mathscr Ey$ and $z\in x/\mathscr E$, therefore $z\mathscr E x \land x\mathscr Ey$.

By *transitivity* of $\mathscr E$: $z\mathscr Ex \land x\mathscr E y \Rightarrow z\mathscr Ey$ and thus:

> $x\mathscr Ey$ and $z\in x/\mathscr E$, therefore $z\mathscr Ey$.

Finally, we apply again Def.6 to $z\mathscr Ey$ in order to derive:

> $x\mathscr Ey$ and $z\in x/\mathscr E$, therefore $z\in y/\mathscr E$.

Thus, applying *Exportation* [see page 19: $[(P \land Q) \to R] \equiv [P \to (Q \to R)]$ ] we can conclude with :

> > $x\mathscr Ey$, therefore: if $z\in x/\mathscr E$, then $z\in y/\mathscr E$,

i.e.

> $x\mathscr Ey \Rightarrow [(z\in x/\mathscr E) \to (z\in y/\mathscr E)]$.

Now we need the so-called [Universal Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) rule ["since $z$ is arbitrary, it follows that ..."; it seems to me that it is not discussed in the book], to conclude with:

> > $x\mathscr Ey \Rightarrow (\forall z) [(z\in x/\mathscr E) \to (z\in y/\mathscr E)]$.

Now, by Def.2 [page 36], we have:

> > $x\mathscr Ey \Rightarrow x/\mathscr E \subseteq y/\mathscr E$.

Comment: Oh exportation law p∧q → r ≡ p → (q→r)! That's enough for me to understand (zEx∧xEy⇒zEy) ≡ (zEx⇒xEy⇒zEy).

Answer (score 0):

At that point in the text, you already know (i.e., have assumed that) $x {\mathscr E} y$. Under that assumption, $z {\mathscr E} x$ indeed implies (and is equivalent to) $z {\mathscr E} y$.

Comment: No my focus is the hypothesis. Different hypothesis produces different conclusion, doesn't it?

Comment: @buzzee Begining from the point where the author writes "Let $x\mathscr E y$", there is no logical difference between $z\mathscr E x\land x\mathscr Ey$ and $z\mathscr E x$.

Comment: Is there a justification that makes [(zEx ∧xEy ⇒ zEx) by Simp. ∧ (zEx ∧xEy ⇒ zEy) by trans.] ⇒ (zEx⇒ zEy) valid?

Answer (score 0):

For part c), two things need to be proven:

- $ x/\mathscr E=y/\mathscr E\implies x\mathscr E y$
- $x\mathscr E y\implies x/\mathscr E=y/\mathscr E$

The first implication is covered by the  "It follows immediately ..."

To prove the second direction, the author starts with the assumption that $ x\mathscr E y$ and the goals is to prove $ x/\mathscr E=y/\mathscr E$. To show equality of sets one can proceed by showing both  $x/\mathscr E\subseteq y/\mathscr E$ and  $y/\mathscr E\subseteq x/\mathscr E$.
To show $x/\mathscr E\subseteq y/\mathscr E$, one starts with an arbitrary element $z\in x/\mathscr E$ and intends to show that  $z\in y/\mathscr E$.
Now, $z\in x/\mathscr E$ means precisely that $z\mathscr E x$. This, together with the initial assumption $x\mathscr E y$ entails $z\mathscr E y$ (as $\mathscr E$ is transitive).
That again means $z\in y/\mathscr E$ as desired.
To summarize the last step: We have shown $\forall z\colon z\in x/\mathscr E\to  z\in y/\mathscr E$, which is just a rewording of $x/\mathscr E\subseteq y/\mathscr E$.

Comment: No, that's not my focus. Your answer just rephrased what's shown in the book. Is there a justification that makes [(zEx ∧xEy ⇒ zEx) by Simp. ∧ (zEx ∧xEy ⇒ zEy) by trans.] ⇒ (zEx⇒ zEy) valid?